# Filter products based on the sub child in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, nosql

I am trying to figure out how to filter products based on their sub child nodes in Firebase.

My setup is as follows:

```
products/
     product1
        /author: 12345
        /title: "Awesome"
        /description: "more awesome"
     product2
        /author: 67890
        /title: "Awesome"
        /description: "more awesome"
```

How can I query Firebase such that I retrieve only the products for which it holds that `child($productId).child(author)` equals `12345`?

I tried the following, but that obviously does not work. I need a way to filter on the subchild:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);

// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
ref.child("products").child('$productId').child('author').equalTo(12345).on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: Ordering/filtering by lower-level children is currently not possible in Firebase. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: I mis-understood your question initially. Filtering on the property of a child node **is** possible. Answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `orderByChild()`:

```
ref.child("products").orderByChild('author').equalTo(12345)...
```

This will order every child node under `products` by its `author` property and then return only the ones that have a value of `12345`.

See [Firebase's documentation on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries).

Comment: Uhm think that your first comment was right actually. The setup is: products/$productId/author where $productId is dynamic. Child of products is not author or does that not matter??

Comment: Ordering on the value of a property of a child is possible. The code snippet I gave will accomplish that.

Comment: Ah sorry! Incredible! It works! Really nice feature of Firebase.