# Filter products on multiple child properties in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, nosql

I recently asked how to filter products based on their child property (see: [Filter products based on the sub child in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526960/filter-products-based-on-the-sub-child-in-firebase/32527536#32527536)).

As a recap my structure looks as follows:

```
products/
     product1
        /author: 12345
        /title: "Awesome"
        /category: "catA"
        /description: "more awesome"
     product2
        /author: 67890
        /title: "Other"
        /category: "catB"
        /description: "otherawesome"
     product3
        /author: 12345
        /title: "Billy"
        /category: "catB"
        /description: "otherawesome"
```

And to filter out all products with author `12345` we can simply use:

```
ref.child("products").orderByChild('author').equalTo(12345)...
```

**However, what to do when I have multiple AND statements or multiple OR statements?**

So what if I want to filter out:

- all products with author `12345` AND category `catA` (returns `product1`)
- all products with author `12345` OR author 67890 (returns `product1` and `product3`)

For the first part, I tried:

```
ref.child("products").orderByChild('author').equalTo(12345).orderByChild('category').equalTo('catA')...
```

but that did not work (throws error `You can't combine multiple orderBy calls`)

See also:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase), the way to do this is to perform the first query (preferably the one that will return the fewest results), then filter by the other field in javascript. Another way to do this, and I'd recommend this if you are performing this query often, is create a compound index for the query like; the answer by Frank van Puffelen in the link above gives an example of this.

```
products/
     product1
        /author: 12345
        /title: "Awesome"
        /category: "catA"
        /description: "more awesome"
        /author_category: "12345_catA"
     product2
        /author: 67890
        /title: "Other"
        /category: "catB"
        /description: "otherawesome"
        /author_category: "67890_catB"
     product3
        /author: 12345
        /title: "Billy"
        /category: "catB"
        /description: "otherawesome"
        /author_category: "12345_catB"
```

As for the 'OR', I've looked for quite a while and found nothing to help you. I'd suggest two separate queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. Yeah I guessed that a compound index would be the best option.